# Difference between map and filter in python

Tags: python

I have the following code(which uses map) to check whether any string in `mylist` is present in any string in `list1` and if it is, the code prints the string from `list1`. This code is working perfectly fine.

```
mylist=['dog','cat','bil']

def check(string1):
    list1=['doggy','abc','def','catelyn','billy']
    for i in list1:
        if(string1 in i):
            return i
x=list(map(check,mylist))
x
```

Now if I keep the code same, and replace map with filter, it prints the substrings(from `mylist`)

```
mylist=['dog','cat','bil']

def check(string1):
    list1=['doghdjd','asnkbakv','bsvbubdb','gfdtcatkbnk','bkkbill']
    for i in list1:
        if(string1 in i):
            return i
x=list(map(check,mylist))
x
```

I am still returning the string from `list1` but the other strings are added to `x`. Why is this happening?

Comment: where is filter ?

Comment: map and filter are completely different functions...

Comment: Have you considered the wild idea of reading the docs for those functions and learning the differences?

Comment: `help(filter)` -> `...yielding those items of iterable for which function(item) is true.` IE the values in the original iterable for which the function returns a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `map` apply the function to each element, so it replaces the value in the array by the result of the function, it's like

  ```
  [check(value) for value in mylist]
  ```
- `filter` applies the function as a test, to know if it keeps the value or not, here as the function always return a string (for the given input) it's evaluated as non-false so it keeps all

  ```
  [value for value in mylist if check(value)]
  ```

---

If you use `list1 = ['doggy', 'abc', 'def', 'catelyn', 'b-illy']`,  `check('bil')` will return `None`, so the filter will not keep `bil` :

```
print(list(map(check, mylist)))     # ['doggy', 'catelyn', None]
print(list(filter(check, mylist)))  # ['dog', 'cat']
```